# Django : can't login in django administration

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

First of all, I've created a User model, which inherits from AbstractUser. I use another model which is called CustomUserManager (which inherits from UserManager). In CustomUserManager, i rewrote the create_user method, and the create_superuser method. When i create a simple active user, it works fine (i can connect the user). When i create a superuser, it works fine ("Superuser created successfully") BUT when i go to the django administration pannel, and i enter the correct information of the superuser, it doesn't work and display the following message : "**Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.** "

Here's my models.py :

```
class CustomUserManager(UserManager):

   def _create_user(self,email,password,first_name,last_name,**extra_fields):
       email = self.normalize_email(email)
       user = User(email=email)
       user.is_active=True
       user.password = make_password(password)
       user.save(using=self._db)
       return user
   def create_user(self,email,password,first_name,last_name,**extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email,password,first_name,last_name,**extra_fields)

   def create_superuser(self,email,password,first_name,last_name,**extra_fields):
       """
       Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
       """
       extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
       extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
       extra_fields.setdefault('is_active',True)

       if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
           raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
       if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
           raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

       return self.create_user(email,password,first_name, last_name, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractUser):
   username = None
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False)
   first_name = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=50)
   last_name = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=50)
   REQUIRED_FIELDS=["first_name","last_name"]
   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
   objects = CustomUserManager()
```

EDIT : Thanks to Max Koniev, I forgot to say, but i already had AUTH_USER_MODEL set to my User model in my application private_portal : AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'private_portal.User'

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you set AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py to your new User model

Comment: I forgot to say it, but i already had AUTH_USER_MODEL set to my User model in my application private_portal :  AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'private_portal.User'

Comment: Not sure what make_password function does, can you check in the shell that it creates it correctly. Try with check_password method of User model.

Actually there is a second one which you can use, set_password.

So you can use `user.set_password(password)` instead of `user.password = make_password(password)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i've changed `user.password = make_password(password)` to `user.set_password(password)`. `user.check_password(password)` returns True.